# Spring Boot 2.7.14 + Java 1.8 + Gateway + https. Error SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT al acceder a traves del gateway

Tags: spring-boot, https, microservices, yml

Muchas gracias de antemano...

Estoy intentando hacer que las peticiones vía HTTPS al gateway se redirijan al servicio correspondiente, pero el navegador me devuelve el siguiente error:

**SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT**

He implementado varios micro-servicios en la aplicación, que están funcionando (Config, Eureka, Gateway y algunos endpoint), pero me está costando aplicar ssl.

Al acceder al endpoint sin pasar por el gateway, este negocia correctamente con el navegador la gestión del certificado (auto-firmado), pero al acceder a través del gateway el navegador me da el error de arriba.

Os pongo el código:

Gateway:

```html
server:
  port: ${app.gateway-server-port}
  forward-headers-strategy: native
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: xxxxxx
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: myCertLocal
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${app.eureka-server-host}:${app.eureka-server-port}/eureka/
    initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds: 5
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 5
    leaseExpirationInSeconds: 5
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          useInsecureTrustManager: true
      routes:
        - id: security
          uri: https://${app.security-server-host}:${app.security-server-port}
          predicates:
            - Path=/security/**
```

Security:

```html
server:
  port: ${app.security-server-port}
  forward-headers-strategy: native
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: xxxxxx
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: myCertLocal
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${app.eureka-server-host}:${app.eureka-server-port}/eureka/
    initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds: 5
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 5
    leaseExpirationInSeconds: 5
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@${app.oracle-server-host}:${app.oracle-server-port}/${app.oracle-service-name}
    username: ${app.oracle-db-owner-name}
    password: ${app.oracle-db-password}
    driver-class-name: ${app.oracle-driver}
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      dialect: ${app.oracle-dialect}
      format: true
app:
  security:
    jwt:
      secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      expiration: 86400
```

El almacén está en el correspondiente  \src\main\resources\ de cada proyecto.

Ya no sé por donde seguir. Agradecería muchísimo cualquier ayuda o sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!

El problema estaba en el certificado que había generado. Al crear uno nuevo, siguiendo este [tutorial](https://www.robertocrespo.net/configuracion-de-https-en-aplicaciones-spring-boot/), ya he podido hacer que el Gateway acepte y redirija las peticiones https. Lo que aún no tengo muy claro es que el primer certificado que generé con OppenSSL funcionaba en cualquier API REST, pero no con el Gateway. La única diferencia entre los certificados es que en el segundo, el que funciona, he añadido en "Subjet Alternative Name"  editando una extensión con "DNS name"(localhost) y la "IP" local(127.0.0.1)

Espero que os sirva de ayuda.

Saludos!